# Create a generic repository with Jooq

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, generics, jooq

We are using JOOQ to map an existing database.  Every table (bar 1) in this database shares a similar set of columns:

```
resource_id:   Int (FK)
id:            Int (PK)
identifier:    UUID
date_created:  DateTime
date_modified: DateTime
```

There is a general rule in the database for all operations that looks something like this:

```
select   * 
from     table t
join     resource r on r.id = t.resource_id
where    r.is_archived = false
```

Using JOOQs generation feature, I can successfully create a repository class that implements the basic query operations:

```
@Repository
class UserRepository(val dsl:DSLContext): IRepository {
    val record = Tables.AUTHENTICATION_USER!!   //generated by jooq
    val resource = Tables.RESOURCE!!            //generated by jooq
    val pojo = AuthenticationUser::class.java   //generated by jooq

    // this is the general query logic that should be applied to all the things
    override fun selectQuery(): SelectConditionStep<Record> {
        return dsl
            .select(record.asterisk())
            .from(record)
            .join(resource).on(resource.ID.eq(record.RESOURCE_ID))
            .where(resource.IS_ARCHIVED.eq(false))
    }

    override fun asyncCount(): Mono<Int> = Mono.fromCallable {
        selectQuery()
            .count()
    }

    fun asyncGetPage(from: Int,
                     size: Int,
                     orderBy: SortField<*> = record.DATE_CREATED.asc(),
    ) = Mono.fromCallable {
        selectQuery()
            .orderBy(orderBy)
            .limit(size)
            .offset(from)
            .fetchInto(pojo)
            .let { Collections.unmodifiableList(it) }
    }
```

Now, this is all well and good, but I am having trouble converting this to a generic implementation that can

- accept a `table` of type `T`
- can recognise those 5 common fields/attributes on the table so we can make our queries generic.

I can get this to work:

```
class GeneralRepository<T: Table<R>, R: Record>(val table: T, val record: R, val dsl:DSLContext) {
    fun asyncGetAll(): Mono<List<R>> = Mono.fromCallable {
        dsl
            .select()
            .from(table)
            .fetchInto(record::class.java)
    }
}

// manually construct it ignoring Springs DI for development
val resourceRepository = GeneralRepository(
    Tables.RESOURCE,
    ResourceRecord(),
    JooqConfiguration().dsl(),
)
```

The problem comes when I try to do anything with the `table T`.  Since `T` is of a generic table type, the compiler has no way of knowing about the fields `id`, `identifier`, `resource_id`, `date_created` etc, meaning queries like this cannot compile:

```
    fun asyncGetAllNonArchived() = 
        dsl
            .select()
            .from(table)
            .where(table.DATE_CREATED > ...)
```

Question:
Is there a way to tell the compiler or declare the generics in such a way that the common fields are available.

---

EDIT:  Thanks to Lukas Eder below for the advice.  Adapting that solution we were able to create a generic repository.

First off, changing the generator strategy to Kotlin let the `Auditable` interface act correctly :)

Secondly, we couldn't find a way with the generic class to implement the `Table` types in terms of the `Record` types, so you have to very slightly extend the signature.

```
interface Auditable {
    fun RESOURCE_ID(): TableField<Record, Int> =
        (this as Table<Record>).field("resource_id") as TableField<Record, Int>

    fun ID(): TableField<Record, Int> =
        (this as Table<Record>).field("id") as TableField<Record, Int>

    fun IDENTIFIER(): TableField<Record, UUID> =
        (this as Table<Record>).field("identifier") as TableField<Record, UUID>

    fun DATE_CREATED(): TableField<Record, LocalDateTime> =
        (this as Table<Record>).field("date_created") as TableField<Record, LocalDateTime>

    fun DATE_MODIFIED(): TableField<Record, LocalDateTime> =
        (this as Table<Record>).field("date_modified") as TableField<Record, LocalDateTime>
}


open class GeneralRepository<R, T>(val table: T) where R: Record, T: Table<R>, T: Auditable {
    val resource = Resource.RESOURCE

    fun selectQuery() =
        dsl
            .select(table.asterisk())
            .from(table)
            .join(resource).on(resource.ID.eq(table.RESOURCE_ID()))
            .where(resource.IS_ARCHIVED.eq(false))
```

You can then easily implement generic extensions:

```
class UserRepo: GeneralRepository<UserRecord, User>(table = User.USER) {

    fun getEmail(email: String) = Mono.fromCallable {
        selectQuery().and(table.EMAIL.eq(email))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you know you can provide an answer to your own question here on Stack Overflow, rather than editing your question. That way, it might be even more helpful for future visitors of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate an interface that provides access to these columns:

```kotlin
interface Auditable {
  fun RESOURCE_ID(): TableField<Record, Int?> = 
   (this as Table<Record>).field("resource_id") as TableField<Record, Int?>
  fun ID(): TableField<Record, Int?> = 
   (this as Table<Record>).field("id") as TableField<Record, Int?>
  fun identifier(): TableField<Record, UUID?> = 
   (this as Table<Record>).field("identifier") as TableField<Record, UUID?>
  fun DATE_CREATED(): TableField<Record, LocalDateTime?> = 
   (this as Table<Record>).field("date_created") as TableField<Record, LocalDateTime?>
  fun DATE_MODIFIED(): TableField<Record, LocalDateTime?> = 
   (this as Table<Record>).field("date_modified") as TableField<Record, LocalDateTime?>
}
```

and then attach the interface to all generated tables using a [generator strategy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/):

```xml
<strategy>
    <matchers>
        <tables>
            <table>
                <expression>T_.*</expression>
                <tableImplements>com.example.Auditable</tableImplements>
            </table>
        </tables>
    </matchers>
</strategy>
```

It is currently not possible to declare properties in the interface because it's not possible to detect whether an `override` modifier is required, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10776.

But this may be good enough for now. You can then create generic conditions like this:

```kotlin
fun <T> dateCreatedCondition(table: T, dt: LocalDateTime): Condition
where T : Table<*>, T : Auditable = table.DATE_CREATED().gt(dt)
```